# visual basic: user inputs a % sign after text

Tags: string, vb.net, char

```
Private Sub btnBillSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBillSearch.Click

        If Me.txbBILL_NR.Text = "" Or Me.txbBILL_NR.TextLength >= 4 Then
            Try
                Search()

                If Me.bsBillGrid.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                    Me.dgvBill.Focus()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Utility.ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex)
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("enter at least 4 numbers")
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have this method for search button in my app.
So, I already wrote the If condition for where user enters a minimum number of characters is 4 to select entries.

I need to one more validation for % sign. I figured out, that is kinda startWidth(), but I do not understand how I can get those situations:

I think about using startWith/endWith or regex maybe.
Could anyone please give me some advice where to look at.

1. user adds “%” sign after txbBILL_NR - the system does not add additional “%” in the background,
   txbBILL_NR with identical part number are found and reflected in the list.
2. the user has not added the “%” sign after the txbBILL_NR - the system adds an additional “%” in the background,
   txbBILL_NR with identical no. parts are found and listed.
   The "%" character does not need to be represented by the user;

3.user added “%” sign at the beginning or middle of txbBILL_NR - the system does not add an additional “%” in the background,
txbBILL_NR with identical part number are found and reflected in the list (no changes required);

4. The "%" system only needs to be marked if the user has entered at least 4 characters in the txbBILL_NR field (assuming that the invoice number cannot be shorter than 4 characters.
5. If the user has entered at least 4 characters (whether they are starting characters or from the middle) and "%" is added to the beginning or middle of these symbols, the system does not add an additional "%" in the background
   the invoice (s) with the identical part (symbol) part are found and reflected in the list.

Comment: Is this VBA? Please, edit your question and properly update the question tags. Your problem can be solved in VBA, too, but this is not the point...

Comment: Seems to be VB.Net?

Comment: it is a visual basic. that's right.

Comment: There are several Visual Basics. Old VB, VBA, and VB.Net. Which one?

Comment: yeah You are right, vb.net it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
'Get raw user entry.
Dim searchText = txbBILL_NR.Text

'Get user entry without wildcards.
Dim cleanSearchText = searchText.Replace("%", String.Empty)

If cleanSearchText.Length = 0 OrElse cleanSearchText.Length >= 4 Then
    If searchText = cleanSearchText Then
        'There are no wildcards so append one.
        searchText &= "%"
    End If

    'Use searchText here.
End If
```

Comment: If searchText = cleanSearchText Then
        searchText &= "%"

If I understand correctly, then % sign goes after the text, what user enters? Right?

Comment: @junior, correct. `searchText` is what the user entered and `cleanSearchText` is that with wildcards removed. If the two are the same then the user entered no wildcards so a wildcard is appended to the input and that will be the search text.

Comment: so far, so good, but % sign goes after the text or in the middle or before text? 
searchText &= "%" how this works? What happens when user puts that % before text like %1234 or 1234% or 12%34%? 
Or I need do smth like this: txt = "%" & searchText & "%"

Comment: It's not really for us to teach you the basics of VB programming but, regardless, I already explained what the code does so I shouldn't need to repeat myself. If you don't understand, why don't you try executing the code and actually see for yourself what it does?

Comment: I already tried, thank you for advice. will learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I think this function meets your requirements.

```
Private Function SearchCriterium(ByVal Crit As String) As String
    ' 295
    
    Const Mark  As String = "%"
    Dim Fun     As String           ' function return value
    
    Fun = Crit
    Do While (Len(Fun) >= 4) And (Right(Fun, 1) = Mark)
        Fun = Left(Fun, Len(Fun) - 1)
    Loop
    If Len(Fun) < 4 Then
        MsgBox "Enter at least 4 characters.", _
                vbExclamation, "Invalid search crterium"
         SearchCriterium = Crit
    Else
        If InStr(Fun, Mark) = 0 Then Fun = Fun & Mark
    End If
    SearchCriterium = Replace(Fun, Mark, "*")
End Function
```

Observe that it replaces the % sign with VBA's wild card character `*`. You can remove that feature if you don't need it at that point.

The function removes any existing trailing placeholder and then adds one if none exists elsewhere in the string. Here is a list of the tests I ran.

```
Private Sub Test_SearchCriterium()
    Debug.Print SearchCriterium("Item")
    Debug.Print SearchCriterium("It%em")
    Debug.Print SearchCriterium("%Item")
    Debug.Print SearchCriterium("Ite%")
    Debug.Print SearchCriterium("It%%")
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you all for the answers. how much do i understand that a wildcard is better to use in such a task?

Comment: Obviously, you want the user to enter `%` as a wild card. How you use this will be shown  in your `Search()` procedure. VBA natively understands `*`. However, you have changed your question to refer to VB.Net. Therefore whatever good you find in my answer, which is VBA, must be translated to that language. The point is the logic I proposed rather than the syntax I used. It's a lot simpler than what you explained and therefore easier to program in any language.

Comment: Variatus, Thank you for advice, I have no such an experience with wildcards and so on. I will go through with your example and learn more about it. 
In a search() method there goes all props in and nothing more. 
In my app I have a textbox where user can enter a Bill_NR like invoice nr. with that % sign and get out in a list all those docs by number.
But yeah thank you!

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as "Selected" - forum rules. If you have another question, this time about how to search for the `BILL-NR.` (with wild cards), do your research, make an own effort, and post your new question according to where you arrive. You can use the search string returned by my function as search criterium. Good luck.

Comment: I would like to select your answer and code, but I can not, because I have no 15 reputation to cast a vote. :(

Comment: I think anyone can "select" an answer. In fact, you earn points by doing so. :-) You just can't upvote until you have collected some.